# How do i get list of Managers with ID?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Users table with following schema,

```
UserId, Name, ManagerId
```

This ManagerId, is nothing but a Userid as a manager is also a user.

I can get list of managers using below query but how do i get managerId along with name ?

```
Select DISTINCT(ManagerId) from Users
group by ManagerId
```

I want following output

```
ManagerId, Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT UserId, Name
FROM Permission
WHERE UserId IN (Select DISTINCT ManagerId FROM Permission)
```

Also possible with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT UserId, Name
FROM Permission AS p1
JOIN (Select DISTINCT ManagerId FROM Permission) AS p2 
   ON p1.UserId = p2.MAnagerId
```

Comment: This should be the most efficient way ?

Comment: I think the second query is more efficient compared to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to retrieve users who are managers. This could be done using `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserId, Name
FROM Permission p1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Permission p2
  WHERE p1.UserId = p2.ManagerId
  )
```

`DISTINCT` clause is optional and may be extraneous depending on your data. If this is the case, remove it for performance boost (distinct requires the input to be sorted and then duplicates are removed).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use `IN` together with `DISTINCT` like Giorgos suggested. SQL Server has a good optimization engine, but I've had bad experience with such statements.

Better use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT P1.UserId, P1.Name
FROM Permission AS P1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Permission AS P2
        WHERE P2.ManagerId = P1.UserId
        );
```

Keep in mind that it would be a good idea to have indexes on `Permission` table where first indexed column will be `UserId` and in another index `ManagerId`. This way `EXISTS` will perform very efficiently.